# Simple console snake game in Python

Tags: python, console, windows, snake-game

Here's a simple snake game I implemented in Python, which works in a console. It's not complete yet (doesn't generate food yet, and no scoring or difficulty levels), but it works. I would be really grateful if you give me any suggestions on how I can improve my code. Note that I did some of the things I did in  a really complicated manner, just to learn new tricks, like the needlessly complicated binary manipulations, but suggestions would be helpful anyway.

All kinds of suggestions would be welcome, but what I really want to know right now, would be how I should accept user input. Should I use threads? If so, how should I implement it? Or should I just poll for input in a `for` loop?

```
import math
import time
import msvcrt
import ctypes
import random

from ctypes import wintypes


   #######  ##     #     ##     #    ##  #######
   #        # #    #    #  #    #   ##   #
   #        #  #   #   #    #   #  ##    #
   #######  #   #  #  ########  ####     ##### 
         #  #    # #  #      #  #  ##    #
         #  #     ##  #      #  #   ##   #
   #######  #      #  #      #  #    ##  #######

   #*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*#
   # A simple command line snake game in Python. #
   #*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*#

########################################################
########################################################

DUMP = False

class GameState:
    field_width  = None
    field_height = None

    field_state = []

    snake_length = 0
    snake_head = [0, 0]

    # dir codes for movement
    #               ** up **
    #                   8
    #
    #   ** left **  4       6  ** right **    
    #
    #                   2
    #              ** down **
    head_dir = 4

    game_lost = False
    snakebody = []

    defaults = {}

    map = None

    def initialize(settings):
        # Initialize functions
        try:
            for prop in settings:
                if not callable(getattr(GameState, prop)):
                    setattr(GameState, prop, settings[prop])
                else:
                    raise AttributeError
        except AttributeError as e:
            e.args = ("Invalid game setting '{}' does not exist.".format(prop),)
            raise

        GameState.snakebody = [list(GameState.snake_head)] * GameState.snake_length
        GameState.defaults = settings

        GameState.loadmap()

        # Make a copy of snake_head
        GameState.snake_head = list(GameState.snake_head)

    def reset():
        GameState.initialize(GameState.defaults)
        GameState.game_lost = False

    def loadmap(file=None):
        if file:
            if not hasattr(file, 'read'):
                file = open(file, 'r')
            GameState.map = [int(line, base=2) for line in file]
        else:
            GameState.map = GameState.map or [0] * GameState.field_height

        GameState.field_state = list(GameState.map)

        if len(GameState.field_state) != GameState.field_height:
            raise Exception("field map is invalid")



WIN32  = ctypes.WinDLL("kernel32")
stdout = WIN32.GetStdHandle(-11)    # stdout code = -11 from header files


def HideCursor():
    class _CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [('dwSize', wintypes.DWORD),
                    ('bVisible', ctypes.c_bool)]

    hidden_cursor = _CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO()
    hidden_cursor.bVisible = False

    WIN32.SetConsoleCursorInfo(stdout, ctypes.byref(hidden_cursor))

HideCursor()

# Useful class
COORD = wintypes._COORD

# Box drawing chars
box_tl = "\u250C"
box_tr = "\u2510"
box_bl = "\u2514"
box_br = "\u2518"

vborder   = "\u2500"
hborder   = "\u2502"

# Helper functions
def move_cursor(pos=(0,0)):
    WIN32.SetConsoleCursorPosition(stdout, COORD(*pos))

def change_dir(dir):
    # Prevent reverse gear
    if (GameState.head_dir + dir) == 10: return
    GameState.head_dir = dir

def move_snake():
    # Default changes
    inc   = 1
    index = 0
    wrap  = GameState.field_width
    dir = GameState.head_dir

    if dir in [4, 8]:
        # to go either left or up, there must be negetive increment
        inc = -1

    if dir in [2, 8]:
        # vertical movement, so change y pos, and wrap vertically
        index = 1
        wrap = GameState.field_height

    GameState.snake_head[index] += inc
    GameState.snake_head[index] %= wrap

    if has_obstacle(GameState.snake_head):
        GameState.game_lost = True 

    GameState.snakebody.insert(0, list(GameState.snake_head))
    tail = GameState.snakebody.pop()

    # update field state
    # -------------------
    # remove tail first
    tx, ty = tail
    GameState.field_state[ty] -= GameState.field_state[ty] & (1 << tx)

    hx, hy = GameState.snake_head
    GameState.field_state[hy] |= (1 << hx)

def has_obstacle(pos):
    x, y = pos
    return bool(GameState.field_state[y] & (1 << x))

def draw_field():
    w = GameState.field_width
    h = GameState.field_height

    # Move cursor to stating point (for overwritting)
    move_cursor()

    # Draw the field
    print(box_tl, vborder * w, box_tr, sep='')

    for i in range(h):
        scanline  = GameState.field_state[i]
        screen_line = [" "] * w

        for pix in range(w):
            if scanline & 1: screen_line[pix] = "#"
            scanline >>= 1

        screen_line = "".join(screen_line)

        print(hborder, end='')
        print(screen_line, end='')
        print(hborder)

    print(box_bl, vborder * w, box_br, sep='')
    if DUMP:
        for i in GameState.field_state:
            x = bin(i)[2:]
            print("0b","0"*(w-len(x)),x, sep='')

def transition():
    w = GameState.field_width
    h = GameState.field_height

    # Transition effect: diamond-in
    move_cursor()

    width_band = 10

    inner_offset = [-i for i in range(h//2)]
    inner_offset += [(i - h) for i in range(h//2, h)]

    outer_offset = [k-width_band  for k in inner_offset]

    last = min(outer_offset)
    pow2 = (1 << w) - 1

    while last < (w//2 + 1):
        for i in range(h):
            in_pos = inner_offset[i]
            out_pos = outer_offset[i]

            r_in = w - in_pos - 1
            r_out = w - out_pos - 1

            gm_st = GameState.field_state[i]

            # Inner left side
            if in_pos >= 0: gm_st |= 1 << in_pos

            # Inner Right side
            if 0 < r_in < w:
                gm_st |= 1 << r_in

            # Outer left side
            if out_pos >= 0:  
                x = gm_st & ( (1 << (out_pos+1)) - 1 )
                gm_st -= x

            # Outer right side
            if 0 < r_out < w:
                x = pow2 - ( (1 << (r_out+1)) - 1 )
                gm_st -= (gm_st & x)

            GameState.field_state[i] = gm_st

            inner_offset[i] += 1
            outer_offset[i] += 1

        last += 1
        draw_field()

        time.sleep(0.01 if not DUMP else 1)

def draw_lostScreen():
    w = GameState.field_width
    h = GameState.field_height

    text = ["GAME OVER",
            "Want to try again?",
            "Enter y to continue, any other button to quit"]

    v_offset = (h - len(text)) // 2

    transition()
    move_cursor()

    print(box_tl, vborder * w, box_tr, sep='')

    for i in range(h):
        print(hborder, end='')
        print(" "*w, end='')
        print(hborder)

    print(box_bl, vborder * w, box_br, sep='')

    for i, t in enumerate(text):
        h_offset = (w - len(t)) // 2
        move_cursor([h_offset, i + v_offset])
        print(t)

    move_cursor([w // 2, i + v_offset + 1])
    return input().lower() == 'y'

GameState.initialize({
    'field_width'   : 75,
    'field_height'  : 20,

    'snake_length'  : 10,
    'head_dir'      :  4,
    'snake_head'    : [75//2, 20//2]
})

# GameState.loadmap('map.txt')

try:
    while True:
        while not GameState.game_lost:
            move_snake()
            draw_field()

            if msvcrt.kbhit():
                dir = msvcrt.getch()
                while msvcrt.kbhit():
                    dir = msvcrt.getch()
                dir = ord(dir)

                if dir == 72 or dir == 56: dir = 8
                elif dir == 80 or dir == 50: dir = 2
                elif dir == 75 or dir == 52: dir = 4
                elif dir == 77 or dir == 54: dir = 6
                else:
                    continue
                change_dir(dir)
            time.sleep(0.03)

        time.sleep(1)
        retry = draw_lostScreen()
        GameState.reset()

        if not retry:
            break
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
input()
```

Comment: With normal console fonts, where the character is higher than wide, it makes playing this a bit awkward ^^"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Refactoring `GameState`

The `GameState` class feels a little odd to me. Is there a reason why it's a static class? This class would be much more useful if you could instantiate it and create multiple, varying `GameState`s, rather than changing the static variables contained inside the static `GameState` class.

The first thing we need to do is add a *"magic method"* named `__init__`. This *"magic method"* is called whenever an instance of the specified class is created, in essence, the constructor. This means that'd you'd define an `__init__` method that looks something like this:

*It was a little hard to tell which variables should be included in the parameters, so I took an educated guess.*

```
class GameState:
    def __init__(self, field_width, field_height, field_state, snake_length, snake_head, head_dir):
        ...

    ...
```

This isn't all though, next, we need to initialize the class attributes, and set them to the values of the parameters. Our `__init__` method now becomes this:

```
class GameState:
    def __init__(self, field_width, field_height, field_state, snake_length, snake_head, head_dir):
        self.field_width = field_width
        self.field_height = field_height
        self.field_state = field_state
        self.snake_length = snake_length
        self.snake_head = snake_head
        self.head_dir = head_dir
        ...

    ...
```

Now that we've done this, all of the `GameState.` prefixes in your `GameState` classmethods should be prefixed with `self.` instead.

Now that you've done this, you should be able to just create a new instance of `GameState` for each individual game, like this:

```
current_game_state = GameState( ... )
```

---

## Defining a main function

Right now, you just have a top-level `while` loop that runs your code. No `main` function, and no `if __name__ == "__main__"` guards. The best thing to do would be to define a main function, and the run it underneath a guard, like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You may think that this isn't very important, but it does do some important things, namely preventing `main` from running if your file is imported, rather than run directly. You can see more on this subject matter [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do).

---

## Style

To start off, it's worth mentioning that Python, unlike many other languages, comes with an official style guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It might be worth your time to take a quick peek at that whenever you have a chance.

To start off, some of your naming is incorrect. Names in Python should follow the following conventions:

- Variables should be in `snake_case`.
- Constants should be in `UPPER_SNAKE_CASE`.
- Function names should be in `snake_case`.
- Class names should be in `PascalCase`.

Secondly, in Python, there's no sort of value alignment, like you've done here:

```
'field_width'   : 75,
'field_height'  : 20,

'snake_length'  : 10,
'head_dir'      :  4,
'snake_head'    : [75//2, 20//2]
```

And here:

```
WIN32  = ctypes.WinDLL("kernel32")
stdout = WIN32.GetStdHandle(-11)
```

There is no need to align the values with extra spaces.

There should also be two blank lines between top-level code/function/class definitions, like this:

```
class Spam:
    ...


def eggs():
    ...
```

And not like this:

```
class Spam:
    ...

def eggs():
    ...
```

Finally, please indent code contained in `if`/`while`/`def`/etc. blocks like this:

```
if spam:
    eggs
```

And not like this:

```
if spam: eggs
```

It helps clear up readability *a lot*. If you're just using the `if` statement to assign a new value to a variable as well, you can just use a ternary, like this:

```
spam = eggs if foo else bar
```

Answer (score 0):

`GameState` is a rather weird class.  You're actually not using it as a class, but as a namespace.  Basically, you have a bunch of global variables that don't look global because they are prefixed by `GameState.`.

You typically don't need to put `…State` in the names of classes, either.  The whole point of object-oriented programming is to have stateful objects.  Instead of naming your class `Game`, though, I'd just call it `SnakeGame`.

Calling `GameState.initialize()` with a dictionary feels more like a JavaScript calque than Python.

A more idiomatic outline of the code would be…

```
class SnakeGame:
    def __init__(self, **settings):
        self.field_width = None
        self.field_height = None
        self.field_state = []
        …
        try:
            for k, v in settings.values():
                setattr(self, k, v)
        …
```

… to be called like

```
game = SnakeGame(field_width=75, field_height=20, …)
```

But then, some of those parameters aren't actually optional.  You should either make them mandatory, or better yet, provide sensible defaults.

```
class SnakeGame:
    def __init__(self, field_width=75, field_height=20, snake_length=10, head_dir=4, snake_head=None):
        self.snake_head = snake_head or (field_width // 2, field_height // 2)
        # Use a tuple, not a list -------^^^
        …
```

---

To answer your question about threads… that would be totally overkill for this kind of game.  Polling should be adequate.  Write a function that [does `msvcrt.getch()` with a timeout](//stackoverflow.com/a/6179750/1157100).